# Calculate only hours minutes seconds from TimeSpan

Tags: vb.net

I have a 7 string in this format 00:00:00
Im trying to use timespan to calculate those strings
the problem is it counts it with days

```
        Dim l1 As String = "14:32:45"
        Dim l2 As String = "07:43:13"
        Dim l3 As String = "00:00:00"
        Dim l4 As String = "00:00:00"
        Dim l5 As String = "18:34:54"
        Dim l6 As String = "00:00:00"
        Dim l7 As String = "12:00:34"
        Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l1)
        Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l2)
        Dim ts3 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l3)
        Dim ts4 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l4)
        Dim ts5 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l5)
        Dim ts6 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l6)
        Dim ts7 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(l7)
        Dim ttsum As New TimeSpan
        ttsum = ts1 + ts2 + ts3 + ts4 + ts5 + ts6 + ts7
         MsgBox(ttsum.ToString)
```

Output : 2.04:51:26

Desired output : 52:51:26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way a `TimeSpan` works. If you don't want the output of `TimeSpan.ToString` then don't use it. You can do your own calculation of the number of hours and use that:

```vb
MessageBox.Show($"{Convert.ToInt32(ttsum.TotalHours)}:{ttsum.Minutes:00}:{ttsum.Seconds:00}")
```